# How do I know if I am connecting to uniswap factory mainnet or testnet if the contract addresses are common for both?

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-invocation, uniswap

I had thought each contract deployment and contract address was unique on Ethereum, including across mainnet and testnets. But in the Uniswap documentation it says:

> UniswapV2Factory is deployed at
> 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f on the Ethereum mainnet,
> and the Ropsten, Rinkeby, Görli, and Kovan testnets. It was built from
> commit 8160750.

source: https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/factory/

If this is the case, how can I choose whether I am connecting to the Uniswap mainnet or testnet factory contract? I am connecting via JavaScript and Truffle as follows:

```
      ...
  
      const UniswapContract = contract(UniswapFactoryAbi);
      UniswapContract.setProvider(this.web3);
      UniswapContract.at('0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f').then(function(instance) {

      ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network you are on depends on the provider you are using. In your case, `this.web3` is associated with some that network that you defined earlier in the code. If you track down what network is associated with `this.web3`, you will know what Uniswap contract that is referring to.

Comment: Thanks great thanks, in my case I was using metamask